# Making woocommerce checkout form state field not required based on selected country

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress+Woo-commerce site and I want to make the state field on the checkout form optional based on the selected country. For example I want my customers to add state field only if they belong to one of U.S.A. states.

How do I do this?

Comment: did you try anything out already?

Comment: Yes but not specific! I am not sure not how to get the selected country. May be I need to add jQuery to detect the selected country and then need to do some magic with AJAX. I am not sure if there is some filter or action hook to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_state_required' );
function custom_override_state_required( $address_fields ) {
  $wc = WC();
  $country = $wc->customer->get_country();
  if($country !== 'US'){
     $address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
  }
  return $address_fields;
}
```

This is code that worked for me. I am posting this answer without editing @zipkundan answer because I don't see any mistakes in his answer but somehow it was not working for me. That may be because of WooCommerce version or may have another reason!! I recommend to try both answers if someone have similar requirements.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone stumbles on this, Woocommerce changed the name of the state fields. Below is the updated solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_default_address_fields' );

function custom_override_default_address_fields($fields){
    global $woocommerce;
    $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();

    if($country !== 'US'){
        $fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = false;
        $fields['shipping']['shipping_state']['required'] = false;
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this (in your functions.php)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
     global $woocommerce;
     $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
     if($country !== 'US'){
        $address_fields['state']['required'] = false;
     }
     return $address_fields;
}
```

This will make the 'state' field optional when the visitor is not from USA.
Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields($fields){
    global $woocommerce;
    $country = $woocommerce->customer->get_country();
    if($country !== 'US'){
        $fields['billing']['state']['required'] = false;
        $fields['shipping']['state']['required'] = false;
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: It's working when the customer choose to ship to the 'billing address' but not working with my setting which is 'ship to shipping address'. Any idea why it is behaving like that.

Comment: On further testing I have found that this is working only if the billing country is selected as USA and it doesn't matter what is selected at the shipping country.

Comment: Well, do you want this to be applicable to both billing and shippings address?

Comment: @Rituparna Sonowal > I have posted updated function. This makes "state" field optional in both billing and shipping forms. Check if it works for you and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting the other answers to work until I realized there's also the `woocommerce_get_country_locale` hook from WC_Countries. Which sets state required based on the chosen country through javascript in the frontend.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'update_country_locales', 10 , 1);

function update_country_locales($countries) {

    foreach ($countries as $country => $fields) {
        if (isset($fields['state']) && $country != 'US') {
            $countries[$country]['state']['required'] = false;
        }
    }

    return $countries;
}
```